# Ram usage is constantly increasing on my azure server running python scripts

Tags: python, mysql, azure, system

### Issue in Brief

I have recently started using an azure server running ubuntu 20.04. My workflow includes running around 50 python scripts 24/7 and they are operationally very important to my team. But the issue when I just start those python scripts my ram usage is nominal like 12/16 GB remains free in my system after running all my scripts.
But slowly RAM usage by those scripts starts increasing to the point where the system starts to kill them to free up some main memory.
I have no idea what the issue is over here. My scripts are pretty simple and I really don't know where and how do I resolve this issue. Can anyone please show/tell me some guidelines on how do I approach solving this issue?

#### Comments

I am using python 3.10. Script function is to download the data from some server and upload it to my MySQL database. I can provide the code if anyone asks for it.
Let me know if I can provide anything else to make this easier for you.

#### Code files

I am uploading the code which is taking up the maximum memory according to htop.

1. **dcx_trades.py**

```
import json
import time
import datetime
from mysql_connector import SQLConnector
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
import signal
from contextlib import contextmanager

def raise_timeout(signum, frame):
    print("timeout")
    raise Exception("timouttt")

@contextmanager
def timeout(time):
    # Register a function to raise a TimeoutError on the signal.
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, raise_timeout)
    # Schedule the signal to be sent after ``time``.
    signal.alarm(time)
    try:
        yield
    except TimeoutError:
        # exit()
        pass
    finally:
        # Unregister the signal so it won't be triggered
        # if the timeout is not reached.
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)

from_db = {'user': 'db_user_name', 'password': 'password', 'host': 'host_url', 'database': 'crypto'}
s = SQLConnector('crypto', from_db)
dict_ = {'timestamp': '', "exchange": "coindcx", "symbol":"", 'error_msg':''}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["exchange_id","timestamp","symbol","price","quantity","exchange","turnover"])
df.set_index('symbol')

while True:
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv('dcx_trades.csv')
        trades = data.to_dict(orient='records')
        data = data.iloc[0:0]
        if len(trades):
            for trade in trades:
                utc_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(trade['T']/1000, datetime.timezone.utc)
                local_time = utc_time.astimezone()
                datetime_formatted = local_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
                dict_['timestamp'] = datetime_formatted
                dict_["exchange_id"] = 12345
                dict_["symbol"] = trade['s']
                dict_['price'] = trade['p']
                dict_['quantity'] = trade['q']
                dict_['turnover'] = float(trade['p'])*float(trade['q'])
                dict_['error'] = '0'
                df = df.append(dict_, ignore_index=True)
            print(df)
            df_new = df
            df_new= df_new.to_dict(orient='records')
            df = df.iloc[0:0]
            data.to_csv('dcx_trades.csv', mode='w', index=False)
            if len(df_new):
                with timeout(60):
                    try:
                        print(datetime.datetime.now())
                        s.add_multipletrades(df_new)
                        print(datetime.datetime.now())
                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        os.execv(sys.executable, ['python'] + sys.argv)
                        print("error_time:", datetime.datetime.now())
    except Exception as e:
        data = pd.read_csv('dcx_trades.csv')
        data = data.loc[1:]
        data.to_csv('dcx_trades.csv',index=False)
        pass
```

**Objective of the file:**

Firstly `s = SQLConnector('crypto', from_db)` this lines makes the connection with the DB. All the database-related functions have been defined in another file named **mysql_connector.py** which I have imported in the beginning.
Then the code reads from the CSV file named **dcx_trades.csv** and preprocesses the data as per the database table. Before uploading the data into DB it clears the CSV file so as to remove duplicates. **timeout(60)** function is used because sometimes the file get stuck while writing into the DB and thus it needs to get restarted which is what **timeout()** function does.

Comment: Is the data in CSV file format?  If so, don't use python code; instead, use MySQL's `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: Does `top` or `htop` or some other tool show which script is growing the most?  If so, let's look at the details of it.

Comment: @RickJames I'll have to use python code because there's some preprocessing that's needed before uploading the data into the DB.
And let me upload the code which is taking up maximum memory.

Comment: probably garbage collection is not fast enough. Let you loop run once and see how much  memory is in use. If it almost doubles every time it runs you have to add a del data before refilling it

Comment: @user3732793 I am already deleting everything in the file before refilling the file. I have other scripts which handle much more frequent data than this one.

Comment: @HimanshuGupta - `LOAD DATA` can do some processing, too.  Can you tune Python's garbage collection?  Perhaps something in the loop is not being freed?  Deleting from the file should be irrelevant.

Comment: @RickJames How can I do this? I've heard python GC is pretty good on its own. But nonetheless, tell me what you want me to try?

Comment: @HimanshuGupta The code posted does not include all the details of 'Step 1' in the tutorial at this URL  -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/connect-python  - verify you are successfully completing conn.close() to release resources when done, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck my scripts run 24/7 I cannot do conn.close() because I constantly use the database connection. Any other suggestion please?

Comment: @HimanshuGupta Please view profile for contact info and get in touch to review some details.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks. Sent you an email with the subject "Stackoverflow". Please check that out.

Answer (score 0):

All of those transforms can easily be done in SQL --

1. `LOAD DATA` into a temp table with whatever columns match the columns and datatypes in the file
2. Run a single `INSERT .. SELECT ..` to copy the values over, doing whatever expressions are needed (such as `p * q`).

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I am looking for. Because I need the solution for other scripts as well they're behaving the same. RAM usage is increasing and everything. And those scripts functions are different from this one. So can you suggest anything else please?

Comment: @HimanshuGupta - If python is the problem, then doing the work just in MySQL _may_ be the solution.

Comment: like I said earlier I cannot use MySQL. Because I have other scripts as well which does not use MySQL but they still are increasing the RAM as time goes on. Which is why I need to figure out what's really causing this issue.